# Should I backup or copy [an Access database file]?

Tags: ms-access, backup

Access has the option of creating a backup of dbase, but is there any difference between doing this and 'saving database as'?

Thanks for your time and patience for the ignorant.

Answer (score 1):

The "Back Up Database" and "Save Database As" options do the same thing. The only real difference is that "Back Up Database" will provide a default file name like

```
MyDatabase_2014-11-18.accdb
```

whereas for "Save Database As" the new name will default to

```
MyDatabase1.accdb
```

They both do what is essentially a "[Compact and Repair](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/compact-and-repair-a-database-HA010341740.aspx)" into a new database file. (The original database file is not compacted, only the resulting copy.)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that much about Access backups but in general the benefit of the a backup is that it is unchanging. Take a backup and you have a snapshot of your data at that point in time. Just making a copy you run the risk of making a change in the copy and losing your snapshot. Of course with an Access file you can zip the copy to prevent changes.